# How to make the content of a page readjust to iframe size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

this is my first question here so please, bear with me.

I have a page with a small gallery, ming I have a few thumbnails that are links so that certain images load onto an iframe. Below that I have text.

Right now, my iframe adjusts to the size of its content which is exactly what I want, also, my images are not all the same size, so when they load to the iframe, they push the text down. 
So far so good.

The problem is that if I load an image with a height of 600px, and then load one with a height of 200px, the text below stays where the 600px image pushed it.

What I want is for the text to readjust to the height of the currently loaded image on de iframe.

Help?

Comment: Can you show the live version or recreate it on jsfiddle?

Comment: If you make a demo on jsbin.com or jsfiddle (I prefer jsbin), I can probably help. This site: http://placehold.it/ will provide you with image placeholders.

Comment: Here is the jsfidle, although I can't seem to get the auto resizing of the iframe to work...

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e5TTG/) @Shomz

Comment: Here is the jsfidle, although I can't seem to get the auto resizing of the iframe to work...

[jsfiddle]http://jsfiddle.net/e5TTG/ @m59

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this for you with`jQuery1.10.2`, this will be set the text's width dynamically depend on your iframes width.
first, add `jQuery` to your page;

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jQuery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

and then give your iframe's width and set this width for your textwrapper:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function resizeIframe(obj) {
    obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
}
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#columnthumb img').click(function(){
        var width = $('iframe').width();//if you want to write it for your img, write img instead of iframe
        //alert(width + '<-----Width');//this is for test and figure out your iframe's width
        $('p.textocorpo').css({'width':width, 'text-align':'justify'});
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: The problem is that I do need to set it dynamically. I need the text to always be right below the iframe, no mater what size it inherits

Comment: is this your text you want to : José Amaro

Disciplina: Design de Comunicação I 
Data:Abril de 2013 
Impressão: Offset

Comment: no... but thank you for the kick reply! I need to turn in my assignment tomorrow so I don't have much time to explore, but thank you so much for all your help and sorry for the trouble. @kiyarash

Answer (score 0):

```
You need to do it like this

Conceptual:
onclick get image height then set image height to iframe height.

Code:

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

$(document).ready(function(e) {

    $('#ImagesColumn img').click(function(){

    var imgHeight = $(this).height();        
        var imgWidth  = $(this).width();        

    $('#iframeId').css({height: imgHeight, width: imgWidth})
    $('p.textocorpo').css({'width':imgWidth, 'text-align':'justify'});


    });

});
</script>
```